# SQL ELSE block still throws error when IF condition is true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, exists

I have the following T-SQL script that copies the value of an old column into a new one, then drops the old column. See here:

```
--step 1: create new column
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns
                WHERE Name = N'UserColumn2'
                AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Account'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Account
        ADD UserColumn2 int null
        ;
    END
GO
;

--step 2: copy and drop
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'UserColumn1'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Account'))
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Column ''UserColumn1'' does not exist.';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Account
        SET UserColumn2 = UserColumn1
        WHERE UserColumn1 is not null
        ;

        BEGIN TRY
            Declare @count int;
            SELECT @count = Count(AccountID)
            FROM Account
            WHERE UserColumn2 <> UserColumn1
            ;
            IF @count > 0
                BEGIN 
                    --PRINT 'Not all records were properly updated. UserColumn1 has not been dropped.';
                    THROW 50000,'Not all records were properly updated. UserColumn1 has not been dropped.',1
                    ;
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    ALTER TABLE Account
                    DROP Column UserColumn1
                    ;
                END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH THROW; END CATCH
    END
GO
;
```

The first step runs correctly but the second step still throws an error in the `ELSE` block even if the `UserColumn1` column doesn't exist:

[image: screenshot of error: "Invalid column name 'UserColumn1'"]
(note: this actually throws on line 24 for the code here. The code in my SSMS doesn't have the comments for 'step 1', etc.)

**Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?**

I've tried removing the `NOT` and moving the instructions out of the `ELSE` block but the behavior did not change. I've also tried writing the beginning of the second step like this:

```
IF (SELECT 1 from sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'UserColumn1'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Account')) <> null
```

and I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the entire sql text is parsed and compiled before it's executed, the error is being thrown at compile time.

You could workaround it by executing the update statement in its own process using dynamic sql - although there is nothing *dynamic* in this usage, it simply defers the compilation and execution of the `update` statement where it only happens in your `else` condition:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'UserColumn1'
        AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Account'))
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Column ''UserColumn1'' does not exist.';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql N'
          UPDATE Account
          SET UserColumn2 = UserColumn1
          WHERE UserColumn1 is not null;'

...
...
```

Comment: I ended up using this for the entire contents of the `ELSE` block and it works great now. Thanks for the clarification.